# Jetpack compose can't preview after updating to 1.0.0-rc01

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

this happened to me only when I updated to 1.0.0-rc01.
it says:

> The following classes could not be found:
> - androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.ComposeViewAdapter (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)

[image]

my code:

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun CenterProgress(){
    Box(
        modifier= Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ){
        CircularProgressIndicator(strokeWidth = 3.dp)
    }
}
```

Comment: According to a comment on Kotlinlang Slack's `#compose` channel, previews will not work until you can upgrade to Arctic Fox RC1, which unfortunately is not available yet.  That same comment suggested that you could drop the tooling dependencies back to `beta09` and they would work with `rc01` for the main dependencies. Note that I have not tried that yet, so I do not know if it would work.

Comment: The solution that @CommonsWare mentioned worked for me on Bumblebee Canary 3.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**Update 07/20/2021:**
Just download and use the [latest AS](https://developer.android.com/studio) to fix the problem

---

They splitted some packages in rc01 but per @CommonsWare comment (all credits to him) it seems there is a problem with Android Studio version itself.
You have 2 options:

1. Downgrade to beta09 until AS ArcticFox RC1 is out
2. Try the suggested workaround, use AS Arctic Fox Beta 5 leaving all compose dependencies to `1.0.0-rc01` version and downgrade only `ui-tooling` to `1.0.0-beta09` (confirmed by comments).

---

**Extra details**

Here you can find all the classes they moved in `1.0.0-rc01` https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1739498 and the explanation on why this has been decided.

In short, you can now do this for some particular optimized scenarios (which should not be the default case):

```
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.0.0-rc01"
```

Comment: I tried and I get this Cannot access 'ComposeViewAdapter': it is internal in 'androidx.compose.ui.tooling'

Comment: That's strange... did you update `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` in the build.gradle? Maybe could be a problem with AS itself

Comment: yes, I did update everything. read the comment above on my question, I think that's the problem

Comment: yes i thinks so, updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Android Studio Artic Fox (2020.3.1) Beta 5 - July 2, 2021. For me it worked the workaround, leave all the compose dependencies to 1.0.0-rc01 version and downgrade only ui-tooling to 1.0.0-beta09.

Comment: downloaded today the latest AS available, created a fresh project and updated stuff to rc01, to be able to preview I had to use a `debugImplementation` of `ui-tooling:1.0.0-beta07";` instead of the rc01 one.

Comment: Doesn't look like fixed using rc02

Comment: @adek111 Nope, will not work until AS ArcticFox RC1 is out :/

Comment: I found this answer very helpful. Getting a different error: "androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewActivity is not an Activity subclass or alias" This is with Artic Fox Beta 5 and compose version 1.0.0-rc02 for the other compose dependencies, but still had to downgrade the androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling version to 1.0.0-beta09 to get the preview to work.

Comment: AS RC1 is out, issue seems fixed for me

Comment: I got the same issue in `2021.1.1 Patch 3`. The `compose` version is `1.2.0-alpha07`. **Downgraded** `UI-tooling preview` and the `debug implementation` to `1.1.1`. It worked. Using Kotlin version `1.6.20`.

Answer (score 77):

For my case, it's because I left my build variant at "release".
Changing it back to "debug" fixes the missing class bug.

[image]

the preview functionality is probably from the following line in build.gradle

```
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
```

Comment: This worked for me too, after I wasted time fiddling around with dependency versions.

Comment: Thank you so much for this comment. It got me a right direction to find out what is wrong in my case

Comment: For the custom type try to use `implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'`

Comment: I added the library above suggested by @Angel Koh, but as a regular implementation not debugImplementation  to my build.gradle(:app) file, and it worked for me in Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1
`implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.4.3"`

Answer (score 32):

I was also facing the same issue with the below library dependency

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.3.3"
```

Then I removed the preview library and used its root library and it's generating a preview for me.

now I am using the below dependency for my project.

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.3.3"
```

***I am talking as of Feb-2023***

Comment: Yes, save my time. I'm in this case.

Comment: I tried several ways above, while only this worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me running on AS Giraffe 2022.3.1

Comment: Fixed it for me as well, running Iguana in 2024

Answer (score 27):

**Update**: This is no longer needed with *Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Canary 6* and *Android Gradle Plugin 7.1.0-alpha06*. Note: Canary 4 already fixed this issue but required a broken version of AGP. This is now also resolved.

In addition to the above answers: here is how to force the ui-tooling version in gradle:

```kotlin
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version") {
    version {
        // TODO: Remove this when Android Studio has become compatible again
        // Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Canary 3 is not compatible with module ui-tooling 1.0.0-rc01 or higher.
        // The Run Configuration for Composable Previews that Android Studio makes expects a PreviewActivity class
        // in the `androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview` package, but it was moved in 1.0.0-rc01, and thus causes error:
        // "androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewActivity is not an Activity subclass or alias".
        // For more, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68224361/jetpack-compose-cant-preview-after-updating-to-1-0-0-rc01
        strictly("1.0.0-beta09")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried it like the comment above me and it actually helped me only that i had to delete the implementation of :

Link to Artic Fox Beta 5:
https://developer.android.com/studio/preview

androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview.
My compose config looks like the following:

```
android {

def compose_version = '1.0.0-rc01'


composeOptions {
  kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "$compose_version"
}

dependencies {
  def compose_version = '1.0.0-rc01'
/**Compose Related*/

    implementation "androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-rc01"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"

    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-beta09"
//    Need to comment this two lines to work on artic fox
//    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
//    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    /**Accompanist*/
    // Coil
    implementation 'dev.chrisbanes.accompanist:accompanist-insets:0.6.2'
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-coil:0.13.0"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"

    /** Material Icons */
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"


    // Jetpack Compose Integration
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha04"
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

To people still get the error when downgrade the ui-tooling library:

Make sure you don't have library that have dependency on ui-tooling:1.0.0-rc01
You can find that out by using *./gradlew app:dependencies* in your android studio terminal

In my case, I'm using com.google.accompanist:accompanist-swiperefresh:13.0.0 which depend on ui-tooling:1.0.0-rc01. Preview is working when I downgrade to accompanist-swiperefresh:12.0.0

Comment: The accompanist versions mentioned are incorrect, they should be `0.13.0` and `0.12.0`. Besides that, great find! Solved my issues.

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me like a boss.

I just replaced below dependency

```
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$latest_version"
```

with this one

```
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$latest_version"
```

Actually 'preview' word in dependency causes problem.

Answer (score 2):

Been messing around with this. I have a project that has several modules and several build variants. For me, the key was to set each variant (except `release`) to be debuggable in its modules' `build.gradle` file:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true // THIS
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
...
}
```

After that, no matter what build variant I had selected the preview would show.

This is on **Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1**

project `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
    ...
}
```

app `build.gradle`

```
android {
    ...
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.3'
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.3.3"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.3.3"
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using custom build type (instead `debug`), you can use `implementation` instead of `debugImplementation`:

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following dependency fixed my issue with the preview in a library module:

```
debugImplementation 'androidx.customview:customview-poolingcontainer:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Was Facing the same issue on Android Studio Giraffe using
compose BOM version (2023.10.01). The Preview was working on the start but stopped after the application got compiled on the emulator.
The issue was solved by implementing both:

```
debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling"

implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview"
```

- Run Gradle Sync
- Clean and Re-build project

Good to go!

Answer (score 0):

This is the configuration that worked for me, I am using **composable in Fragmen**t and the preview was not showing.

```
implementation(platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.00'))
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
```

Answer (score -1):

On my case, where I have a "design system" module providing all compose-related dependencies, I had to add the following dependency:

```
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0")
```