# androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewActivity is not an activity subclass or alias

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I updated my compose and kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion to `1.0.0-rc02` from `beta09`, Kotlin  version to `1.5.21`, Gradle version to `7.1` and Gradle plugin version to `7.1.0-alpha04`

Ever since - on trying to run `MyScreen` - I'm getting this error:

> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewActivity is not an activity
> subclass or alias

I am not able to resolve this. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio 2020.3.1 RC1 ?

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotte, yes.

Comment: Should I not use this version?

Comment: See this question: [Jetpack compose can't preview after updating to 1.0.0-rc01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68224361/jetpack-compose-cant-preview-after-updating-to-1-0-0-rc01/68412956#68412956)

Comment: with release 1.0.0 I have the same error for my project :/

Answer (score 12):

I am using Compose 1.0, Kotlin 1.5.10 and Android Studio 2020.3.1, and I run into the same problem on most of my previews (not on others).

On the top bar menu, clicking on "*Edit configurations*" and manually creating a new configuration with the same parameters as those in the invalid configuration with warning `(" androidx.compose.ui.tooling.PreviewActivity is not an Activity subclass or alias")` did the trick for me.

Comment: Same problem on 1.0.1/1.5.21 and the workaround proposed in this answer works.

Answer (score 8):

I'm experiencing this error using Bumblebee (AKA, 2021.1.1) Canary 6, 7, and 8, using compose version 1.0.0, 1.0.1, and 1.1.0-alpha01. I've just raised a bug on the Studio issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196248459

To quote myself:

> It seems clear this is a "left hand doesn't know what right hand is doing" thing, because `PreviewActivity` is not in that package, but rather `androidx.compose.ui.tooling` – it hasn't been in `android.compose.ui.tooling.preview` since compose *1.0.0-beta09*.

### UPDATE

I was able to get previews working again by clearing off all the preview run configurations. Here were my steps:

1. Click on the "run configurations" selector and select *Edit Configurations...*
2. Expand the *Compose Preview* grouping
3. Select all the preview configurations (you can select the first and shift-select the last)
4. Click the `-` button to *remove* all the collections
5. Click `Ok`
6. Run *Invalidate Caches...* in the file menu
7. After AS restarts and your cache repopulates, run a preview. It should work now.

Apparently AS was caching "junk" in the temporary run configurations it was creating every time I launched a preview. The "junk" was valid for earlier versions of AS, but broke later versions. Clearing out this cache got me working again.

Comment: The update works for me. Thanks. I got this error after upgrading from Kotlin `1.5.10` and Compose `1.0.0` to Kotlin `1.5.21` and Compose `1.0.1`.

Comment: Same here (1.0.0 -> 1.0.1 & 1.5.10 -> 1.5.21), but removing preview configs, invalidating caches and restarting did not fix the issue.

Comment: But can confirm that [Anton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68602802/359832) did.

Comment: Removing the "Compose Preview" in configurations did the trick for me. no need to invalidate cache.  (using Compose 1.0.1)

Comment: I found that running _Just Restart_ from the _Invalidate Caches / Restart_ menu was enough. No need to invalidate caches.

Answer (score 4):

I've got the same error with Compose `1.0.0` and Kotlin `1.5.10` (which is recommended).

[image]

I fixed these with adding the following dependence `debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"` in my gradle file.

Don't forget to set the version of the dependence to your current compose version.

[image]

After a rebuild and reload of the preview everything works fine for me.

The Preview of the example looks like this:

```
package com.example.compose.basics.ui

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.Card
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.shadow
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import de.db.dbs.travio.compose.basics.themeing.ComposeBasicsTheme

@Preview
@Composable
fun ScreenContent() {
    ComposeBasicsTheme {
        Card(modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
                .shadow(8.dp, RoundedCornerShape(32.dp))
        ) {
            Text(
                    text = "Hello World!",
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing that worked for me was downgrading the ui-tooling version to beta09, i.e using this dependency for ui-tooling:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-beta09"
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the `compose_version` to `1.0.1` , and `kotlin-gradle-plugin` to `1.5.21` fixes the issue if the versions used are lower than mentioned here.

Comment: Compose version `1.0.1` and kotlin-gradle-plugin version `1.5.21` does not work for me.