# androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewActivity does not exist - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose

I have been dealing with this issue where while running a preview of a composable, I recieve and error

```
Error while executing: am start -n "com.site.app/androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER --es composable com.site.app.ui.MainActivity.MainAppPreview
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.site.app/androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewActivity (has extras) }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.site.app/androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
Failed to launch an application on all devices
```

I checked the package structure and the `PreviewActivity` does not exist at `androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview` but it's avaialble at `androidx.compose.ui.tooling`.

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68499039/androidx-compose-ui-tooling-preview-previewactivity-is-not-an-activity-subclass) but it's old and basically invalidating cache did not resolve the problem for me.

I am targetting

- compilesdk version 34 due to latest stable nav version 2.7.4.
- compose version 1.5.3
- using hilt as well
- using `implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.5.3"`
- using `debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.5.3"`

It seems to me that the problem lies somewhere around the gradle versioning as the path at which it is checking for PreviewActivity is itself wrong. I tested the behaviour on an older project and things were fine even the path was also correct.

Comment: This can happen if you have not imported the androidx.compose.ui.tooling library, or if you have not included the library in your project's build.gradle file.

Comment: @JaspalsinhGohil Already using tooling libraries. Updated the question as well.

Comment: try like this implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.5.3" remove debugImplementation and also update  this also implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.5.3-rc02" and check if its working or not

Comment: @JaspalsinhGohil As per this https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling tooling:<version> is for debug implementation. I don't think it should work with implementation. Moreover, I tried adding rc02 but no luck. It doesn't seem to be a versioning issue as the PreviewActivity is available in the structure. While previewing it is not referencing to the correct path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected, the issue was with the compose version. During the course of development compose version `1.5.4` came in, which resolved the issue of `PreviewActivity` being referenced from `androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview`

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue with the below library dependency

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.3.3"
```

Then I removed the preview library and used its root library and it's generating a preview for me.

now I am using the below dependency for my project.

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.3.3"
```

Comment: I have a similar setup in another project where it's working with both tooling preview and tooling. I don't think that's the issue. Probably something wrong with the compose version 1.5.3 that I am using currently!

Comment: Try out it on old project by changing the ```composeCompiler``` version