# Jetpack Compose PreviewActivity is not an activity subclass or alias

Tags: android, preview, android-jetpack-compose, tooling

As I am exploring `JetPack Compose` and `Tooling` for it, I came across the wonderful `PreView` feature of it. Although I can see the preview in Split and Design window, when tried to deploy it in an emulator, I found this error.

> androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.PreviewActivity is not an activity
> subclass or alias

I am using

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox| 2020.3.1 RC1
activityComposeVersion = "1.3.0-rc01"
composeVersion = "1.0.0-rc02"
kotlinVersion = "1.5.10"
```

I was trying to deploy preview of [GradientTintedIconButtonPreview()](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetsnack/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetsnack/ui/components/GradientTintedIconButton.kt)

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun SquareComposablePreview() {
    Text("Hello World")
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun ComposablePreview() {
    Text("Hello World")
}
```

These two Composable is identical. For `SquareComposablePreview` the preview runs without an issue, but for `ComposablePreview` is am getting the error.

Am I doing something wrong of there are issue with the tool !

Comment: Are you using kotlin 1.5.10?

Comment: yes, kotlin 1.5.10

Comment: I get the same error when I use the deploy icon in the editor gutter, while deploying via the deploy icon in the preview works.

Comment: See this question: [Jetpack compose can't preview after updating to 1.0.0-rc01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68224361/jetpack-compose-cant-preview-after-updating-to-1-0-0-rc01/68412956#68412956)

Comment: The solution didn't worked for me. I can see the preview, but can't run them on emulator.